# What game is this short chiptune sound from?

Tags: game-identification

Does anyone have an idea where this sound is from?

https://on.soundcloud.com/cyWpawigV6EpqAqn8

From its style, I assume it's from an older game, but I don't quite know.

Some more information for clarification:

- the sound comes from some kind of quiz with different kinds of puzzles, a previous stage included the very prominent sound from the movie Inception, so this sound is probably also related to a more or less popular piece of media
- I can only assume that the sound originates from a game, as it strongly reminds me of older arcade games

Comment: Can you provide the quiz name?

Comment: @pinckerman it's a digital scavenger-hunt hosted by a local software company, all we got for the current stage was this sound